# Darken the outer part of the dialogue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog, but I want to darken its outer part.

Because I want it to stand out from the background a little.

```
private fun cancelOrder() {

    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    val bindingDialog =
        DialogConfirmationBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(binding.root.context),
            binding.root,
            false
        )
    dialog.setView(bindingDialog.root)
    val alertDialog = dialog.create()

    val window = alertDialog.window
    val params = window?.attributes
    params!!.dimAmount = 0.8f //I wrote this code but it didn't work
    alertDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent)

    bindingDialog.apply {
        buttonCanceDialog.setOnClickListener {
            
            buttonConfirmDialog.isClickable = false
            alertDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
    alertDialog.show()

}
```